# Detect Skype Incoming Call

Tags: windows-10, skype

I am using Win 10 and the latest version of Skype (Ver 8).

I would like to make an application that alerts one to incoming Skype calls.

I've been doing Windows development since the mid-80s, but have not kept up with the latest technology.

Skype currently plays a sound and pops up a window on Windows 10 when a call is received. For those who are deaf, unless seated in front of the computer, they will miss the call.

The solution is to flash a bulb when there is an incoming call instead of/or in addition to playing the sound.

There are Wi-Fi addressable smart bulbs that can be flashed. Does Skype notify Windows there is an incoming call?

I'm just guessing (hoping) that Skype generates a Windows message upon receiving a call. A Windows message is sent to all running applications and can be used to have a program flash a Wi-Fi bulb.

Is this true? Is there a notification method that Skype uses to announce an incoming call to Windows? Can someone point me in the right direction? Is something like this already available?

Thanks,
Barry.